# Query concerning to Path to executable

Tags: path

Path to executable is set to; D:\e\p\d\i\tomee\bin\x.exe //RS//x_1176 but i am not clear why there is a space next to .exe file and what //RS//x_1176 represents.

I can see this exe file in D drive but don't find x_1176 anywhere.
Please help me understand this concept.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to give more context for the question you're asking. What programming language are you using? And post the code that you used to generates that path

Comment: What you pass to a command line after the executable and a space, is considered an argument for the executable. So, the `//RS//x_1176` is the argument to your executable. Your program will do something with it.